# Change the result language of Google's PlaceAutoComplete widget

Tags: android, autocomplete

I'm using PlaceAutoComplete widget (full screen mode) by following the instruction in this link [PlaceAutoComplete widget](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget). Everything went fine, I got autocomplete result appeared when I typed any valid place/city name. The autocomplete result showed in English, like "North Java, East Java, ect."

My question is, how can I get the autocomplete result in other language? Say I want it in French or Bahasa instead of English.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this simply depend on the user's system language?

Comment: I didn't know that. If it so, is there any way to get the autocomplete result different than user's system language?